# ntdll.dll unknown function in call stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've got my symbols loaded from the Symbol Servers yet when I get a crash on app close, I have lots of unknown functions in Microsoft dlls. My symbols are loaded, so why no decent call stack?

Comment: Post the call stack you are getting at crash.

Comment: I have the same problem. I see "unknown function" for all Microsoft system dlls although pdb files loaded successfully. This didn't happen for me with VS 2010.